# Laravel 5.1 y $Http angularjs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, angularjs

Estoy intentando acceder por medio de `$http` a la ruta `'App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@store'` de laravel, pero la ruta no me carga o no se encuentra, con php artisan route:list me aparece que esa es la ruta. Cómo puedo acceder a esa ruta o cómo puedo acceder a culaquier ruta siempre y cuando me sirva para descargar datos de bd

**Codigo AngularJS (Angular 1)**

```
app.controller('DatosController', function ($scope,$http)
{
$scope.consultDate = function ()
{
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@store'
        })
    .then(function ( { data })
    {
        // hacer algo con el array de datos
    },
    function (response)
    {
        // callback de error
        console.error(response.statusText);
    });
};
```

});

**Codigo Laravel**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return "Algo";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo recordar que las acciones de Laravel como la que hay en tu código no se reconocen como URL validas, por lo que no puedes usarlas en AngularJs.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@store'
}).then(function(response) {
    // ...
});
```

Tendrás que sustituirla por la url correcta. Algo del estilo `/report/store`.

Por otra parte, veo que estas intentando acceder al metodo store que en los controladores de tipo `Resource` de Laravel se accede con el método `POST`en lugar de `GET`. Tu código quedaría más o menos así:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/report'
}).then(function(response) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en el código, tienes slash, en vez de, backslash.

```
    url: 'App/Http/Controllers/ReportController@store'
```